# Xcode build can´t find file in derived data folder

Tags: xcode, react-native

I have a react-native app, which i wanted to start on ios. But the build-process in xCode fails with the following error:

file not found: /Volumes/Disk/XCode/Derived_Data/App-hksageyxjqizoydwjhxhihcbnxxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.app/App

It´s my first time building an App with xCode. I think this derived data is created by xCode, isn´t it? So how it can happen, that xCode is looking for something there what is missing?

Unfortunately i don´t have any idea, how to get closer to a solution.

Thanks in advance, for some help.

EDIT:
After cleaning, and rebuild, the same error appears:

> Ld
> /Volumes/DISK/XCode/Derived_Data/APP-hksageyxjqizoydwjhxhihcbnxxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APP.app/PlugIns/APPTests.xctest/APPTests
> normal (in target 'APPTests' from project 'APP')
> cd /Volumes/DISK/Projekte/COMPANY/PROJECT/ios
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
> -target x86_64-apple-ios12.0-simulator -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk
> -L/Volumes/DISK/XCode/Derived_Data/APP-hksageyxjqizoydwjhxhihcbnxxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
> -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/lib
> -F/Volumes/DISK/XCode/Derived_Data/APP-hksageyxjqizoydwjhxhihcbnxxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
> -F/Volumes/DISK/Projekte/COMPANY/PROJECT/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks
> -F/Volumes/DISK/Projekte/COMPANY/PROJECT/ios/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current
> -F/Volumes/DISK/Projekte/COMPANY/PROJECT/ios/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks
> -F/Volumes/DISK/Projekte/COMPANY/PROJECT/ios/Pods/GoogleMaps/Base/Frameworks
> -F/Volumes/DISK/Projekte/COMPANY/PROJECT/ios/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks
> -F/Volumes/DISK/Projekte/COMPANY/PROJECT/ios/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks
> -F/Volumes/DISK/Projekte/COMPANY/PROJECT/ios/Pods/GoogleUserMessagingPlatform/Frameworks/Release
> -F/Volumes/DISK/XCode/Derived_Data/APP-hksageyxjqizoydwjhxhihcbnxxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UserMessagingPlatform
> -iframework /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks
> -iframework /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.3.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks
> -filelist /Volumes/DISK/XCode/Derived_Data/APP-hksageyxjqizoydwjhxhihcbnxxv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/APP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/APPTests.LinkFileList
> -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -bundle_loader /Volumes/DISK/XCode/Derived_Data/APP-hksageyxjqizoydwjhxhihcbnxxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APP.app/APP
> -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Volumes/DISK/XCode/Derived_Data/APP-hksageyxjqizoydwjhxhihcbnxxv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/APP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/APPTests_lto.o
> -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lc++ -lc++ -licucore -lsqlite3 -lstdc++ -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreImage -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreText -framework CoreVideo -framework Foundation -framework GLKit -framework ImageIO -framework JavaScriptCore -framework LocalAuthentication -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework MobileCoreServices -framework OpenGLES -framework
> QuartzCore -framework SafariServices -framework Security -framework
> StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework
> WebKit -framework XCTest -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker
> __entitlements -Xlinker /Volumes/DISK/XCode/Derived_Data/APP-hksageyxjqizoydwjhxhihcbnxxv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/APP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPTests.build/APPTests.xctest-Simulated.xcent
> -lPods-APPTests -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Volumes/DISK/XCode/Derived_Data/APP-hksageyxjqizoydwjhxhihcbnxxv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/APP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/APPTests_dependency_info.dat
> -o /Volumes/DISK/XCode/Derived_Data/APP-hksageyxjqizoydwjhxhihcbnxxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APP.app/PlugIns/APPTests.xctest/APPTests
>
> ld: file not found:
> /Volumes/DISK/XCode/Derived_Data/APP-hksageyxjqizoydwjhxhihcbnxxv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APP.app/APP
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
> invocation)

Unfortunately i can´t share the repository, because it´s not my own app, i'am just trying to help someone.

Comment: Yes, the derived data is... derived by Xcode. Try a “Clean” and then a “Build”. The clean will clear the derived data and the rebuild will recreate it. If that does not work, you may have some other minor issues going on. Post your results as an update in your question.

Comment: Can you please provide the full repo with the ios project structure?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Unfortunately i can't provide the full repo. But i updated the full Error message, after clean and rebuild.